# How can I change my footer?

Tags: 7

I am trying to change the footer on a Drupal 7.2 site.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Curiousity: are you "really" using Drupal version 7.2? Could it be that your missing a digit near the end? Also, are you aware of the security risk resolved in 7.32 ? Consider editing your question if needed (to indicate the correct version).

Comment: I start to think that the "footer" is actually a display of one of the menus being used in this site. Refer to my edited answer for more details. And consider editing the question to add the name of the theme you're using, or confirm that you're using a custom theme ...

Answer (score 4):

It's ether in a block or in your template. First check the block admin page at `admin/structure/block`, and look in the section of footer (or something like that). If there is nothing there, it will be in your template. Most likely it will be located in `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a block footermenu with Region footer. But when I change the Region to none the footer is still appearing

Comment: You might want to double check you theme then to make sure it's not being included in the template.

Comment: Where do I check it?

Comment: It will be located in your theme folder. It looks like your using a custom theme, so it should be located at site/all/themes/yourtheme. Depending on the theme, it may be in a sub directory, but your looking for page.tpl.php. Search that file for the footer, and if those links are hard-coded in there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is shown in the image in the question, I can think of 2 possible implementations of that footer being shown:

- it's a display of **one of the menus** used in this site.
- it's **a block** shown in the footer of this site.

Both possibilities are further detailed below ...

### Display a menu in the footer

There are themes that have configuration options to yes or no show a menu like the navigation menu, primary menu, secondary menu, etc. If you use such options to actually show such menu, then the theme will typically put it in some spot on the page where it seems appropriate.

In this specific case, it could well be that (eg) the theme option to display the secondary menu (or maybe the primary?) is turned on, and that the theme in use will actually dispplay it in ... the footer! So to get rid of "that" footer, find the theme option related to it, and disable that option. That should make it disappear.

### Showing a block in the footer

Create an appropriate block and move it to the theme region of your choice. The block content can be whatever you'd like it to be, e.g. some custom HTML.

As of Drupal 7, you can use PHP as the Text Format of a block also, so you can add things like so also:

`<?php echo date("Y"); ?>`

That way, it will always display the correct year (instead of hardcoding it and then changing it each year) ...

If you'd rather not want to use such PHP based approach, you might also want to consider the [Copyright Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/copyright_block) module. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... creates a block that allows you to configure a copyright message that automatically updates using the current year from the server that your site is hosted on.
>
> It does this by adding a new token called [copyright_statement:dates] that you can place within your message. A start year when needed, and the date separator can be changed if needed.
>
> A default message is provided that includes the `[site:name]` token.

To configure the `[site:name]` token, navigate to /admin/config/system/site-information of your site.

If the site name is there and the name does not show up, then it's problably something related to the settings of the theme you're using. To check that, navigate to /admin/appearance of your site, and use the **Settings** link of your theme. Then verify if there are any options related to showing or hiding some copyright message.

PS: Consider editing your question by including the name of the theme you are using ...